# Can I check if a JavaScript function is called from a button's onclick attribute?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function that can be called either from a button click or from another function.

I am working on a simple game made with vanilla JavaScript and I have a function as below:

```
function end() {
  // End the game
}
```

which can be called from a button click:

```
<input type="submit" id="endBtn" value="End Game" onclick="end()">
```

and can also be called from another JavaScript function:

```
function play() {
  // Game logic
  end();
}
```

The game can be ended by either the user clicking on the button or if certain conditions in the play() function are met.

Is it possible to know if the function is called from a button click?

Comment: The downvote isn’t likely based on the topic asked, but on the presumed lack of effort shown. Do you have any code examples to show? What research have you already done?

Comment: Most likely it's possible by introducing an extra parameter.

Comment: If its called from a button click. It should get passed an event. You could infer the mere presence of the event parameter (i.e. its not undefined) or you could check the target property of the event to see if its a specific dom element. It may be easier and more robust to just wrap the function in another function and call that in one of the two places.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I apologise. I honestly thought there was no need to provide code examples to a question like this. I'll keep this in mind

Comment: @MilkTable no worries. If in doubt, always check out the FAQ. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 2):

As by default functions called from events are automatically passed an event value, you can check to see if the `event` value is not equal to `undefined`. Code example:

```js
function yourFunction(event = undefined) {
    if (event && typeof(event) == "object") {
    alert("Called from element")
  } else {
    alert("Not called from element")
  }
}

yourFunction()
```

```html
<button onclick="yourFunction(event)">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there may be a workaround. Give your function a string parameter for ex $notifier.
When calling from button click give $notifier parameter as 'button' or whatever meaningful.
So from there by checking the parameter value you can get to know from where the function is fired.

```
function myFunction(notifier){
    if (notifier=='button'){
        // triggered from button
    }
    else if(notifier=='function'){
        // triggered from function
    }
}
```

and on button -> onclick="myFunction('button')"

Comment: Would you mind sharing a code example? Showing is much better than telling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to assess whether it was called from a button click, see below:

```js
btn = document.getElementById("btn");
testDiv = document.getElementById("testDiv");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const payload = "called from button";
  randomFn(payload);
});


function randomFn(getInput) {
  testDiv.innerHTML = getInput;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>

<div id="testDiv"></div>
```

Comment: The test div is invisible in the snippet output

Comment: @evolutionxbox, yes, correct, it's invisible. Once the button is clicked, it will be updated with innerHTML.

Comment: I see, so it’s not to demonstrate clicking a non-button element?

Answer (score 0):

Just let the function accept a string like "calledBy", like:

```
function myEvent(calledBy){
   if(calledBy=="button") //It has been called by the button
   else //It has been called by function
}
```

In your other function you pass "func" as parameter, while in the button you pass "button"

```
function secondFunction(){
    //Do Stuff
   myEvent("func");
}
```

In your button:

```
...onClick=myEvent('button')...
```

Hope to be clear, there might be other solutions, but this is the first thing that came in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get this is by adding another parameter to the function that will allow you to differentiate the source. I.e. if you have a function

```
function abc(argument1) {
//logic
}
```

You could add

```
function abc(argument1, argument2){
if (argument2 === 'button' {
  //some logic
}
//logic
}
```

If you call it from the button, you can call it with `onClick: () => abc(argument1, 'button')` so you know it came from the button. If called elsewhere, you would change the argument provide from `'button'` to whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

the `this` in the element `onclick` will pass the element itself
so you can check if it's an element or not

```js
function test(ele) {
    if (ele instanceof Element) {
        console.log("this is call by click button");
    } else {
        console.log("this is call by other way");
    }
}

test();
```

```html
<button onclick="test(this)">ckick me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do. However, if you truly must log/check if it was a button click or called from another function, you can do something like this:

```js
function triggerFromFunction(d) {
  triggerClick(true);
}

function triggerClick(comingFromFunction = false) {
  document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = 'Coming from Function = ' + comingFromFunction;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="triggerClick()">Trigger Click</button>
<button onclick="triggerFromFunction()">Trigger Function</button>
<p id="show"></p>
```

This solution is based on ES2015. Otherwise you can check if parameter is undefined in an if statement and proceed from there. Checkout:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_default_parameters.asp

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is look at the function parameters, specifically `event.type`, which all events will pass, if it has no params it must have been called directly (though you can pass a type if you wanted)

```js
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const result = document.getElementById("result");

button.addEventListener("click", theFunction);
button.addEventListener("mouseover", theFunction);
button.addEventListener("mouseout", theFunction);

function theFunction(e) {
  if (e && e.type) result.innerHTML = 'from ' + e.type
  else result.innerHTML = 'has no type, perhaps theFunction()'
}

theFunction({type: 'foo'})
```

```html
<button id="button">Click</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I apologise in advance if what I am about to ask seems silly. Does the if statement in  ```function theFunction(e)``` check if the event exists?